# Autenticação / Permissões com MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, autenticação

Estou estudando o MEAN stack, estou gostando bastante, e estou desenvolvendo aplicações simples, porém, não consegui achar algo que realmente me ajudaria a entender melhor sobre a autenticação e permissões utilizando o MEAN, e como ficaria meu banco.
Agradeceria muito se alguém conseguisse me ajudar, um link de um source demo, um material que não fosse de difícil compreensão ajudaria muito.
Agradeço a todos desde já.

Comment: Veja se pode ajudar: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/wa-mean5/

Comment: Você está usando algum framework?
Se tiver usando mean.js, na pasta serve de cada módulo você controla boa parte das permissões em route e policy.
No client mas pasta route tem a opção também.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, o MEAN utiliza o Mongo, Node e Angular. Além disso você pode fazer a autenticação de várias formas. Com o Angular você poderá aplicar um Interceptador e após validar as informações em seu servidor através de uma requisição get, se retornar 401 você poderá encaminhar o usuário para uma página de "Não autorizado".

O paradigma de persistência no MongoDb é um pouco diferente do que estamos acostumados no banco de dados relacional.

Talvez esses dois links te ajudem:
[Autenticação Passport no NodeJs](http://passportjs.org/)
[Interceptadores no angular js](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Qualquer coisa é só falar.